# AFNetworking SSL pinning is not working. All my server request are passed even if i provide wrong certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking

I tried to set security policy. It seems its not working for me. All api request succeeded even if I do not attach certificate in application bundle. I am writing below code in my custom class init. Is I am doing something wrong.

```
- (instancetype)initWithSessionConfiguration:(nullable NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration {

   if (self = [super init]) {
   self.urlSessionManager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
   self.urlSessionManager.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
   }

   return self;
}
```

Comment: I was using AFNetworking version 3.0. I updated pod to 3.2.1 and everything is working fine

Comment: HI @Ankit Garg, I am also facing same Exception...

Can you please help me on this, How you resolved this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525821/afnetworking-3-2-0-a-security-policy-configured-with-can-only-be-applied-on-a-m

Comment: I was using network logger due to which ssl pinning was not working . Second I updated to version. 3.2.0 everything is perfectly fine using certificate with public pinning mode