# AFNetworking 3.2.0 'a security policy configured with can only be applied on a manager with a secure base url (i.e. https)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ssl, afnetworking

Recently I have updated my iOS App's AFNetworking pods **from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0.** 
AFNetworking3.2.0 Having issues like Crashing the app withe bellow error

***`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid Security Policy', reason: 'A security policy configured with`AFSSLPinningModeCertificate`can only be applied on a manager with a secure base URL (i.e. https)'`***

After Executing code then the app Crashed

***`Which is working fine when switch back to old version with AFNetworking_3.1.0 But crashing on 3.2.0`***

I also trying **operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;** But no use

Please guide m is there anything else I need to improve upon for AFNetwrking3.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this Pull request: 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/3687

It clearly mentions that `AFHTTPSessionManager` instance configured with an insecure `http` **base URL will throw an exception**.

To use `AFHTTPSessionManager` from `3.2.0` onwards you'll have to switch to a secure `https` base URL if you are setting the security policy configured with `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate` or `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey`